# jQuery's delegate() does not bind events for AJAX loaded content

Tags: ajax, jquery, delegation

I want to use jQuery's .delegate() method as I've read it performs much better than .live().

However, when I use .delegate() it doesn't bind events to the ajax loaded content.

Can anyone help me get .delegate() working? Or am I stuck using the slower .live() for ajax loaded content?

```
   var randomObject = {

     'config' : {
       'form' : '#someform',
       'select' : '#someselect',
       'container' : '#pagecontainer'
     },


     'init' : function() {  

        randomObject.formEffects();
        randomObject.ajaxFormSubmit();    
    },


     'formEffects' : function() {

        ////////////// DELEGATE WON'T WORK on AJAX loaded content!
        //$('randomObject.config.form).delegate('select', 'change', function() {
        $(randomObject.config.select).live('change', function() {
           $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
        });
     },


     'ajaxFormSubmit' : function($form) { 

        $(randomObject.config.container).load($form.attr('action')+' '+randomObject.config.container, $form.data('form_values'), function(response, status, xhr){
           alert('updated!');
        });
     }, 

  };
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `form`, `select` and `container`? How does your HTML look like? If `form` gets replaced because of the update process, then of course binding an event handler to it does not work.

Comment: In your commented out code, you have an oddly placed opening single quotation mark. `$('randomObject.config.form)` Perhaps that played a role?

Comment: single quotation mark was a typo when I was writing up the question, not in the code I was running. HTML was <div><div id="ajax-replaced-content"><form><select></form></div></div>. As TommyB suggested, the fix was to bind delegate to the outer div (previously I had been binding it to #ajax-replaced-content so it would only work before the ajax call was made and the div was replaced).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't comment yet as I don't have permission. But with delegate, you need to bind the event above the content that is refreshed via AJAX. So if you're only reloading part of a page, don't set the delegate on content that is part of that page

```
<script>
 $('#parent').delegate("a", "click", function(){
   // AJAX CODE replaces the contents of #parent but not parent itself
});
</script>
<div id="parent">
      <div id="ajax">
          <a href="#">example</a>
          <p>Some content</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

I think in the case above this should work as the delegate is bound on #parent and #parent is not being updated. Obviously this is all pseudo code, but are you reloading the item that you delegate from? If so I think you would need to rebind the events. I'm pretty sure 'live' events get bound to the document and it then just compares the target to make sure it matches the selector. Delegate starts at the selector you specify so the event doesn't need to bubble up as far. (from what I understand)

Comment: You were right I was binding the event to a selector within the content to be replaced by the ajax calls. So the fix was to bind delegate to a div outside of the ajax reloaded content and voila it worked!....So the moral of the story: 1. use .live if you want to bind to a selector within reloaded content, 2. use .delegate on a selector outside of content to be replaced. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this article, really helpful and answers your question.

[The Difference Between jQuery’s .bind(), .live(), and .delegate()](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/)

the short story, `delegate()`needs a container to work on, and takes parameters like `live()`.

Answer (score 2):

A more recent solution is to use the "on" event, which fires also for  ajax-added-elements:

```
$("#mySelector").on("change submit", "form", function (e) {
      //do something
}
```

In this example I want to so something when the form change or submit event has been fired.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(randomObject.config.container).delegate('select', 'change', function() {
```

As **patrick dw** noted, if the only `select` element you're targeting is `#someselect` then you can do this:

```
$(randomObject.config.container).delegate(randomObject.config.select, 'change', function() {
```

Comment: +1 but perhaps: `$(randomObject.config.container).delegate(randomObject.config.select, 'change', function() {` to target just that one select.

Comment: `randomObject.config.select` is a selector string `'#someselect'`. If the element matching that selector doesn't appear on the page until later, then once it is finally added, the `.delegate()` placed on the container will begin to invoke its `change` handler as events are emitted from that element.

Comment: Hmm perhaps... I'll edit the question to mark that. I thought the OP was adding multiple selects

Comment: Yeah, there are a few things that are unclear in this question. I guess I've assumed that based on the selector that is being passed to `.live()`. But you're right, he seemed to switch to a different selector in the `.delegate()` line that is commented out.